# How to add arrays to an arrayList without replacing other arrays in the list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have been working on making a calendar in Java. In doing so, In order to store the information input while the application is running, I have exported the information to a txt file. Now, at the beginning of each application run, I want to get the stored information from that file to fill the calendar. Code wise, this means I want to store each line in a given slot of an array and then append the array to an arrayList:

```
String[] arrInfo = {eventName, eventLocation, eventTime, identifier};
    for(int i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
    {
      line = br.readLine();
      arrInfo[i%4] = line.toString();
      if((i+1)%4 == 0)
      {
        HashMap<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
        String name = arrInfo[3]; 
        map.put(name, arrInfo);
        events.add(map.get(name));
      }
    }
```

I use the map to name the arrays and append them to the array list (events). My problem is that when I leave the code as is, the last array to get added to the arrayList replaces all the other arrays, as my array arrInfo is located outside the for loop and thus is referenced with the same information over and over when it is called for in the end. When I put this array in the for loop, however, it is unable to store all the information for the array (as it just gets remade over and over without storing more than one String). Any help telling me how to add the array so that it is unique each time would be appreciated.

SOLUTION(thanks to Tusar):

```
String[] arrInfo = {eventName, eventLocation, eventTime, identifier};
    for(int i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
    {
      line = br.readLine();
      arrInfo[i%4] = line.toString();
      if((i+1)%4 == 0)
      {
        HashMap<String, String[]> maps = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
        String name = arrInfo[3]; 
        maps.put(name, arrInfo);
        events.add(maps.get(name));
        arrInfo = new String[4];
      }
    }
```

Basically, for anyone interested, just reinitialize the array at the bottom.

Comment: why don't you try `Map<String, List<String>>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  String[] arrInfo =new String[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
      line = br.readLine();
      arrInfo[i%4] = line.toString();
      if((i+1)%4 == 0)
      {
        events.add(arrInfo);
        arrInfo =new String[4]; // re-initialize the array
      }
    }
```